# Lost in Translation ending

Tags: dialogue, ending, lost-in-translation

At the end of Lost in Translation (2003), Bill Murray whispers in Scarlett Johansson ear some inaudible words. What were those words if by any chance there was some kind of any speculation based on the movie plot and events breakdown.

Appreciate any help.